# Django: calling objects from db returns <Queryset [...]>

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.11

I'm trying to get a very simple blogging application up, with all of the posts in my db displayed at once. However, my four posts are presented on the page as

```
<QuerySet [<Post: Test content>, <Post: Second test post>, <Post: Third time's the charm>, <Post: Here is a post.>]>
```

I'm also unable to pass any second variables to the html template like I would flask: testvar doesn't show up at all, even though it is in the html template. Are these problems related? How can I get multiple variables on the page, and how can I make the posts look like regular text?

views.py:

```
  1 from django.shortcuts import render
  2 from django.http import HttpResponse
  3
  4 from .models import Post
  5
  6 def post(request ):
  7     testvar = "TEST VARIABLE PLZ IGNORE"
  8     post_list = Post.objects.order_by('id')
  9
 10     return render(request, 'posts/main.html',
 11             {'post': post_list}, {'testvar': testvar},
 12     )
```

models.py:

```
  1 from django.db import models
  2
  3 class Post(models.Model):
  4     content = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
  5
  6     def __str__(self):
  7         return self.content
```

main.html:

```
  1 <head>                                                      
  2   <h1>{{ post }}</h1>
  3
  4 </head>
  5
  6 <body>
  7   {{ testvar }}
  8   {% for i in post_list %}
  9   <li>i</li>
 10   {% endfor %}
 11 </body>
```

I'm new to django, so I'd appreciate any other advice or criticisms. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to pass a *single* dictionary to `render`:

```
return render(request, 'posts/main.html',                              
    {'post': post_list, 'testvar': testvar},
)
```

Your template wouldn't give you the output you claim, because you never show either `post_list` as a whole, or the contents of each element in the loop. Presumably what you mean is:

```
{% for i in post_list %}
    <li>{{ i }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit** As Sayse points out in the comment, you have a mismatch between variable names. You are passing the list of posts as `post`, so when you do `{{ post }}` in the template you print the whole list. There is no variable called `post_list` at all, so that loop at the bottom of the template never even executes.

You should use consistent names; `post_list` seems more appropriate.

```
return render(request, 'posts/main.html',                              
    {'post_list': post_list, 'testvar': testvar},
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `views.py` change the return statment to:

```
return render(request, 'posts/main.html', {'post': post_list, 'testvar': testvar})
```

Because the third argument of render expects a single dictionary. Also in order to render posts in your template, you should print posts as

```
{% for i in post_list %}
    <li>{{ i }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `context` should be a single dictionary with as many key:value pairs as you need

```
  6 def post(request ):
  7     testvar = "TEST VARIABLE PLZ IGNORE"
  8     post_list = Post.objects.order_by('id')
  9
 10     return render(request, 'posts/main.html',
 11             {'post': post_list, 'testvar': testvar},
 12
```